# Count number of items in Realm Object List not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm, swift4

I'm trying to count the number of exercises in a Realm List (contained within a "WorkoutSessionObject") to populate the right number of rows for a tableview but for some reason I can't work out it isn't letting me access the property?

It's definitely retrieving the WorkoutSessionObject because I've tried printing it.

Here's the code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

//filter for a specific workout
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "workoutID = %@", workoutID)
    let workoutExercises = realm.objects(WorkoutSessionObject.self).filter(predicate)

//access the 'exercises' list and count it - this isn't working?
    let numberOfExercises = workoutExercises.exercises.count
    return numberOfExercises
}
```

I've accessed the properties in a similar way for populating the cells but I'm obviously using index.row there.

The error I'm getting is

**Value of type 'Results' has no member 'exercises'**

on the line that is marked as not working in the code

**Research** there is an answer here [Retrieve the List property count of realm for tableview Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652919/retrieve-the-list-property-count-of-realm-for-tableview-swift) but that doesn't seem it would return the count in scope (it allows a print in the example but this isn't working in my code)

i.e. I've also tried this, which doesn't work because the count isn't accessible outside the scope :

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "workoutID = %@", workoutID)

//the below works to count but then not accessible outside scope to define number of rows :-(

        let workoutExercises = realm.objects(WorkoutSessionObject.self).filter(predicate)
        for exercises in workoutExercises {
            let exerciseCount = exercises.exercises.count
            return exerciseCount
        }
//return exercise count for table rows - this doesn't work because not in scope
        return exerciseCount
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You're returning from your 'for' loop, which isn't what you should be doing. If you want to know how many exercises you have, you'll need to increment the count, then return the final tally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that Realm's `filter` keeps the original type (just like Swift's built-in `filter`), so the type of `workoutExercises` will actually be `Results<WorkoutSessionObject>` and not a single `WorkoutSessionObject`.

If you know that the `workoutID` property of the `WorkoutSessionObject` is always unique, you can simply call `first` on the `Results` instance.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "workoutID = %@", workoutID)
    let workoutExercises = realm.objects(WorkoutSessionObject.self).filter(predicate).first
    return workoutExercises?.exercises.count ?? 0
}
```

If you know that there will always be a matching `WorkoutSessionObject`, you can force unwrap `workoutExercises`.

If `workoutID` is actually a primaryKey, its even better to use `let workoutExercises = realm.object(ofType: WorkoutSessionObject.self, forPrimaryKey: workoutID)` instead of the filtered query.

Comment: I've added the primary key and changed the query as suggested - it's writing to Realm successfully but now crashing before it loads the tableview with the error of "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Index 1 is out of bounds (must be less than 1).'
*** First throw call stack:"

Comment: Ah thanks - even that question helped.  I quickly googled break points and found it was another point in my code i was using the predicate method as above.  Not sure why that breaks after i set the primary key but i've changed it to the primary key filter now and it works fine - thanks!